# Contact not appearing on salesforce marketing cloud for Mobile Push

Tags: contact, c#, mobilepush, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I have created marketing cloud android sdk bindings for xamarin. I have all the required information to configure sdk to my app. I have set custom contactKey but it's not showing on marketing cloud server.

I am not sure what's went wrong ? sdk bindings which I created or sdk Implementation in app.

here's my code

```
public class MarketingCloudChannelManager :
    PushNotificationChannelManager<string, IDictionary<string, string>>,
    IPushNotificationChannelManager<string, IDictionary<string, string>>
{
    private readonly string _applicationId;
    private readonly string _accessToken;
    private readonly string _fcmSenderId;
    private readonly string _mcServerUrl;
    private readonly string _mId;
    private readonly int _iconId;
    private readonly Func<Application> _applicationProvider;
    private readonly IScheduler _dispatcher;

    public MarketingCloudChannelManager(
        IScheduler dispatcher,
        string applicationId, 
        string accessToken,
        string fcmSenderId,
        string mcServerUrl,
        string mID,
        int iconId,
        Func<Application> applicationProvider
    )
    {
        _dispatcher = dispatcher;
        _applicationId = applicationId;
        _accessToken = accessToken;
        _fcmSenderId = fcmSenderId;
        _mcServerUrl = mcServerUrl;
        _mId = mID;
        _iconId = iconId;
        _applicationProvider = applicationProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task InnerOpenChannel(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var application = _applicationProvider();
        var sdkListner = new SdkListner(application, _openChannelTaskCompletionSource);

        var config = MarketingCloudConfig
            .InvokeBuilder()
            .SetApplicationId(_applicationId)
            .SetAccessToken(_accessToken)
            .SetSenderId(_fcmSenderId)
            .SetMid(_mId)
            .SetMarketingCloudServerUrl(_mcServerUrl)
            .SetNotificationCustomizationOptions(NotificationCustomizationOptions.Create(_iconId))
            .Build(application);

        MarketingCloudSdk.Init(
            application,
            config,
            sdkListner
        );

        MarketingCloudSdk.RequestSdk(sdkListner);
    }

    public override Task CloseChannel(CancellationToken ct)
    {
    //  MarketingCloudSdk.Instance.PushMessageManager.DisablePush();

        return base.CloseChannel(ct);
    }

    private class SdkListner :
        Java.Lang.Object,
        MarketingCloudSdk.IInitializationListener,
        MarketingCloudSdk.IWhenReadyListener
    {
        private readonly Application _application;
        private readonly TaskCompletionSource<string> _taskCompletionSource;

        public SdkListner(Application application, TaskCompletionSource<string> taskCompletionSource)
        {
            _application = application;
            _taskCompletionSource = taskCompletionSource;
        }

        public void Complete(InitializationStatus status)
        {
            if (status.IsUsable)
            {
                var invokedStatus = status.InvokeStatus();

                if (invokedStatus == InitializationStatus.Status.CompletedWithDegradedFunctionality)
                {

                    if (status.LocationsError())
                    {
                        GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.ShowErrorNotification(_application, status.PlayServicesStatus());
                    }
                    else if (status.MessagingPermissionError())
                    {

                        this.Log().ErrorIfEnabled(() => "Location permission was denied.");
                    }
                }

                _taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(default(string));
            }
            else
            {

                var error = status.UnrecoverableException();
                _taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(new MarketingCloudException("Could not configure the SDK Error: {0}".InvariantCultureFormat(error?.LocalizedMessage)));
            }
        }

        public void Ready(MarketingCloudSdk sdk)
        {

            var success = MarketingCloudSdk.Instance.RegistrationManager.Edit().SetContactKey("JPX123456").Commit();

            string contactkey = MarketingCloudSdk.Instance.RegistrationManager.ContactKey;

            var sdkstate1 = sdk.SdkState.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

FYI:There is no error, sdk is usable.

success = true and contactKey = "JPX123456"

from sdkstate1 I found out that deviceToken for firebase is null, I not sure that is the reason or not.

can someone clear my understanding and let me know if I am missing any part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, as of 20190328, "we do not support Xamarin in the Marketing Cloud Mobile Push SDKs."

That said, enable logging and check the output for any errors.  I suspect you're missing something in your Xamarin bindings with regards to a Receiver or Service required by the SDK to handle the return result from Google for a device token.

Comment: Thanks! I found out that I am missing PushMessageManager class which I am trying to add, but then I have to setPushToken which I will get from FCM, right ?

Comment: If register for push manually with Google, yes.  The SDK _can_ take care of that for you if we're the only push provider you're using within your application.

Comment: It should be noted that if you're intending to fetch a token and provide it to the SDK then you should *NOT* provide a SenderID to the Marketing Cloud Config. ref.: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html

Comment: Adding manual fcm_push_token solve my problem which I retrieve using Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging
I am also handling onTokenRefresh()